# Named Columns (RTF) option does not appear while Creating Report Layout

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Named Columns (RTF) option does not appear while Creating Report Layout in oracle APEX
[SEE IN IMAGE BELOW-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wecyT.png)
[What are to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7sMI.png)

Comment: Did you **carefully** follow steps presented in that Youtube video?

Comment: Please Help me .......

Comment: I can't *draw* "Named Columns (RTF)" option on your screen. It is either there, or is not. Unfortunately, it is not - in your case. I saw that there's difference between your Apex version and the one presented on Youtube video. Though, it is a *slight* difference so I guess that it shouldn't be the cause. That's why I asked whether you did (or did not) follow instructions, step-by-step (though, there's quite a lot of unnecessary clicking, going forth and back in that video, but hey - you want it quick and dirty. Consider reading the documentation instead).